# Md-dialog count down

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to add a 30 second countdown to a mdDialog popup to visualize the 30 second setTimeout before calling a function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow, AngularJS and Angular are two different things, which one do you use? Please edit your tags accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: @Ploppy Hey thank you! It's AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

How about a md-progress-linear inside the mddialog?
You could add a $interval that changes the value of the progress bar every 1000 msecs. Wrap the whole thing in a function/component so you can reuse the code and hand over a function you want to call afterwards and a limit, in your case 30 seconds.

Comment: can this be done in the js file or does it have to be in the html?

Comment: You can append HTML-Code as a template to the dialog if you don't want to define it as a HTML-file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$timeout` to create the timer.

```
$timeout(function () {
   functionNameHere();
}, 30000);
```